# VBA Excel-Validation causes corrupt workbook file

Tags: excel, vba, validation, xlsx

In Excel VBA a cell-validation may be defined using the following function:

```
myRange.Validation.add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= xlBetween, Formula1:=myListString
```

If `myListString` is longer than 255 characters, Excel reports an error when opening the file and tries to 'repair' the file without concise informations. All validations, diagrams, buttons and shapes are removed during repait and the file is not really useful afterwards.

Is there a way to repair the .xlsx file manually?

Comment: When saving the same File as old Excel 2003 .xls file, the file behaves stable. Only the overlength-validation is removed.
Furthermore, the long validation works fine during runtime, only when the file is opened again, the problems occure.

Comment: I had a somewhat similar problem with a long list and an `.xlsm` file.  Don't recall the details but I **DO** recall that saving the file as `.xlsb` solved the problem. Some opined it might have to do with an XML issue.  Try it and see.

Comment: Also, if you are using VBA, and save the file as `*.xlsx`, the VBA will be removed so all of your VBA generated stuff will be removed. You should have received a warning when trying to save a macro file as xlsx!

Comment: Thank You Ron, the case is not related to vba.

Comment: OK.  Did saving it as `.xlsb` make any difference with either issue?  Both xlsx and xlsm files are saved in a compressed (zip'd) xml format.  xls and xlsb use a different format.  That was the real issue with my problem. *(And I only brought up VBA since you posted some vba code, but if it's not in your workbook, then it is irrelevant to the issue)*

Comment: Ron, Sorry for being so elliptical in my last comment.
I used vba to create a validation list with a string longer than 255. And found, that saving always works. Concerning opening the workbook, I found that excel does not report any errors in an `.xls`-format and just removes the validation string if longer than 255 chars. All other formats (`.xlsx`, `.xlsm` and `.xlsb`) are reported currupt and repaired by removing all validations, shapes and diagrams.
I have a workbook that contains such a validation and saved it as `.xlsm'. I'll check, if editing the xml leads to a workbook that opens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159328/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-drmarbuse).

Answer (score 3):

Thank You, Ron Rosenfeld for the discussion and hints.

In Excel validations of list-type, the string that either holds a range-name or range-adress may not be longer than 255 characters. 
Manually it is not possible to define longer strings. In VBA, however, the string length of the property `formula1` **is not limited**.

Workbooks with such overlength-validations may be stored in any format without any problems.

When re-opening them, the old Excel 2003-format (`*.xls`) just shows empty lists instead of the overlength-validation-string. Newer formats (`*.xlsx`, `*.xlsm` and `*.xlsb`) are reported corrupt and are crudly repaired by dropping many items, as described in the quesiton.

It is possible to repair corrupt `*.xlsx`, `*.xlsm` files by untzipping their contents to a directory and editing the sheetn.xml - file. There the validation string may be edited and shortened. I used 7zip to unzip the file-contents, notepad++ to pretty-print the xml and edit it and 7zip to rezip the file.

The validation in the uncompressed file `xl\worksheets\sheet1.xml` might look like the following:

```
<dataValidations count="1">
    <dataValidation type="list" allowBlank="1" showInputMessage="1" showErrorMessage="1" sqref="A1">
        <formula1>"C16 (S7),C24 (S10),C30 (S13),C35,C40,D30,D35,D40,D50,D60,D70,GL24h (BS11),GL24c,GL28h (BS14),GL28c,GL32h (BS16),GL32c,GL36h (alt),GL36c (alt),C20,GL20h,GL20c,GL22h,GL22c,GL26h,GL26c,GL30h,GL30c,GLT24,GLT30"</formula1>
    </dataValidation>
</dataValidations>
```

Reduce the length of the `<formula1>`-tag, rezip all the files and you may open the file without troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Option:

I like the validation as replacement of comboboxes as they do not need any *active-X* component nor additional *form-elements* are required.

However, I set up a system of spread-sheets with a central *AddIn* that gets list entries from a central database. The list is set to all validations. User defined functions are then used, to get values corresponding to the selection in the validation cell.

Instead of dynamically filling the validation strings on `Workbook_Open`, I changed to a method using named ranges instead.

The Addin has a named range (say `AddinList`) that gets its contents using a user defined matrix-VBA-function returning the list as array (say `public function myList() as variant`).

In any consumer workbook, another name is defined referring to the external Addin-name (say `consumerList=addin.xla!AddinList`). 
Finally, any validation in the consumer workbook is defined as a list that may contain any of the `=consumerList` entries.

The only requirement is, that the addin-file is open, wich is the case anyways, if the consumer workbook is linked to the addin.

Comment: I was trying to do the same thing but failed. Could you maybe elaborate. I have a list of entries that I get from a function similar to your `myList()` function. I just cannot get it to work for validation. Is that reference to the reference necessary?